# Mechanical energy when ball is falling

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, drag, viscosity, dissipation

I could not understand  why mechanical energy of ball is not constant when time passes when a ball is falling in liquid with terminal velocity.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanical energy is $E=K+U$.

- Kinetic energy $K=\frac 12 m v^2$
- Gravitational potential energy: $U=mgh$

When terminal (constant) speed is reached, $K$ is constant. But the ball still falls, so $U$ decreases. The energy is lost as heat because of friction.

Comment: So mechanical energy is not conserved

Comment: @search Exactly, as you said yourself.